# How do I process large amounts of HTML data in an AJAX-heavy application?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Should I have my server return JSON data and then have the JavaScript parse it to create / render HTML directly or should I have my server-side code return HTML directly, which can be directly placed by the JavaScript.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think we'll be able to help you come to a better conclusion if you supplied some metrics and perhaps an example of the data being returned/rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Render the code server side (e.g. as it is done in Rails' AJAX), then return the view to the client where it will just be placed.
Then profile your code. If it turns out to be too slow, return the JSON and think of a way to render it client-side.

Your priority for this should be to not make the whole thing too copmlicated.

Comment: I'm not agreed with this kind of design decisions because you're talking like if refactoring code to support JSON or any other serialization method would be as trivial as "go and change". If you start a project, first think, then do things.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with your perspective of simplicity.

Comment: I mostly have experience with Rails for bigger web projects. But in Rails... Yeah, it's go and change:)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a fan of returning generated HTML. IMHO I'd return JSON and use something like [JQOTE 2](https://github.com/aefxx/jQote2) to handle the rendering. Let the clients resources handle that work.

(Side note: JQOTE is an amazing tool!)

Comment: Why are you not a fan of returning generated HTML?

Comment: I'm just not. There are so many things that make it feel... just not right for a lack of better words. Presentation changes now have to be done server side resulting in recompiling a project. What if you want to expose functionality via an API? Now you have make a complete separate set of functionality to return something consumable such as JSON or XML. I don't want my designer to have to dig through server code to fix a cross browser issue or typo which means tasks aren't going to get delegated properly. To each their own, I support many projects that are written differently than I'd want

Comment: Why is the method of creating the AJAX XML different than creating the initial XML (generally users have to visit a page to initiate an ajax request).  Are you telling me you would prefer that all of your server side scripts print JSON and javascript parses it every time and translates it into HTML?  Are your web programmers so incompetent that they can't print HTML and you need web designers to parse it from JSON?  What if you needed a page to work without javascript?

Comment: The question was in the context of AJAX requests returning HTML or JSON. If javascript isn't used then this whole topic is pointless. In regards to reusable functionality; what would you as a developer rather consume, JSON or HTML? Again these are ajax calls so SEO isn't a factor. The benefits of caching is just as easy with JSON, it's less bloat on the wire with JSON, there is more separation of business logic and markup. I'm not belittling other tactics as I haven't down voted any other answers. This is merely my own suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you won't need the data later, e.g. for filtration, on-the-fly search, etc, then you should return HTML.

Comment: And what about network traffic? Even without needing filtering or whatever, what about of saving network traffic and CPU load, then use less resources and save money by requiring not so impressive server machine? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Premature optimization is the root of all evil.  Start with whatever is easier.  If it's just too slow, find a way to optimize (perhaps by using an alternative).

If one is not easier than the other to you, go with the server side.  I can't imagine a circumstance where a server side scripting language operation would be slower than javascript in a browser.

If all you have to do is render HTML, then it's probably much easier to do it directly with the server (php).  Otherwise, you have to convert it to JSON with php first, then convert it back with JS later.  That's at least one extra step *and* extra work for the javascript side.

Comment: I'm not agreed too with your point of view. First of all, like another comment I made to @x10, I believe that using JSON or render XHTML in server-side isn't that trivial and it couldn't be based on metrics or whatever. It's one of most important design decisions and such web site would be developed in different and incompatible ways depending on this decision. Ah, do you find complicated parsing JSON with jQuery? $.parseJSON(text)? It's trivial. It's not premature optimization, it's a design decision before creating a wrong castle.

Comment: I'm not talking about triviality of code, I'm talking about triviality of execution.  First of all, you should not even need to parse JSON from the text to begin with because the return type should be JSON.  I'm talking about reading the JSON code to translate it into HTML (what??).  Second, your comment about "isn't that trivial and couldn't be based on metrics" makes no sense whatsoever.  How are you creating the initial HTML?  Why is this different than how the AJAX HTML is created?

Comment: I find a difference in writing the html in the server-side and send it through the network, and just send serialized objects. And the infraestructure for working with both solutions is absolutely different.

Comment: I find a difference in writing JSON in the server side and deserializing and updating the DOM /slowly/ with javascript.

Comment: You're absolutely outdated then. Have you ever reviewed latest Web browsers? It's just a suggestion, because JavaScript performance in desktop and laptop Web browsers is x10 than some years ago. If we're talking about mobile Web, then, render XHTML in server. But I believe that this isn't the topic :)

Comment: I can't believe you think it's faster to arbitrarily turn JSON into XML instead of printing XML with php.  Where do you get this data from?

Comment: Have you read the question? It talks about AJAX. Starting a Web request and get a Web response works with plain HTTP and JSON strings are transmitted as plain text. Do you find heavier that than doing roundtrips with XHTML whenever some client needs to refresh something? With PHP or any other language in the world would be better to put the work in the client than in the server if it's about rendering CLIENT user interface.

Comment: XML is also transmitted as plain text over http.  The difference in size between an XML blob and a JSON blob that was structured to become identical XML would be trivial.  How would you construct this blob?

Comment: Haha, do you really believe an XML and JSON string for the same data are almost identical or the difference is trivial? We're talking about the size and network traffic that will generate both solutions. And it's not "plain XML" XHTML: there're more things in the ground. I believe you'll need to re-think some points!

Comment: Just an small sample: <hello text="wassup" /> or {hello:"wassup"}. 23 characters vs 16 (a difference of 7 characters). Now multiply that by 1000, 23000 vs 16000, and so on. At the end of the day, with JSON roundtrips you saved lots of megabytes in a large site.

Comment: You will save a lot more on UI improvement than trivial data size differences.  Your XML can also easily be reduced to only 19 characters if it is such a concern.  What about when dealing with named attributes in the JSON?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid either.  It needs two additional characters (quotes around hello)

Comment: I mean, are you sure this quots would enforce any argument?

Answer (score 1):

I'll vote for your first proposed approach.

JSON serialized data size is smaller than (X)HTML one and your first approach saves a lot of CPU cicles, network traffic, memory and speeds-up your client, which ends in a responsive user interface.

Just send data in JSON format and parse it in JavaScript in the client-side so things will be more simpler in the server and rendering things will be delegated to client web browser.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one right answer; it depends on your expectations.

If you want the application to be accessible (ie. processed by a screen reader), picked up by search engine bots or want the UI to be cacheable between requests and users, you will have to use server generated HTML and no dynamic loading. If you use a cache for the generated HTML, you get a lot of mileage without the constant re-rendering. There are more server side tools than client side but that is becoming less of a true statement as JS grows.

OTOH, producing JSON that is rendered by the client using some JS library can really help your server reduce load. You're distributing the work of rendering to the client but that does take control out of your hands. If you have a JS heavy solution and the client can't process JS (screen readers, search engine bots, etc), then the site should degrade gracefully or expect to have some audience that can't view it. That audience might be minuscule for you but it's something to know. As long as you manage the rendering well, (set min size for areas, wait icons, etc) then you can have client side rendering that is as smooth as server side (when comparing visual rendering steps). Producing JSOn also gives you more flexibility as more interfaces are defined or other non-UI clients become important.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you are writing a mobile application you may want to save bandwidth and work with client-side templates (just as an example: [John Resig's micro templates](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)). If bandwith is not that important to you I would just use server-side templates to generate the HTML you need.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's all about responsiveness. Your server is ALWAYS going to be able to process data faster than the UA, however the difference between the two may be negligible. If that's the case, then I'd recommend passing JSON to the UA and then use client-side code to do the dirty work. That way, you'll have clear separation of concerns between the server and the client, allowing you to deliver JSON data to different client endpoints in the future without having to modify your server-side code.

However, if there is a significant performance hit with doing the data processing on the client side then it might make more sense to deliver HTML directly to the client. **HOWEVER** I highly recommend that you still deliver JSON, only to your server-side HTML creation function (rather than the UA) so that you can still deliver JSON data to multiple endpoints without having to alter core code in the future.